# How can I maintain the space between these two buttons in IE7 mode?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have 2 buttons horizontally aligned. In most browsers there's a space between them, but if you view this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2HP43/1/

in "Browser Mode: IE7" & "Document Mode: IE7 Standards" you can see that the 2 buttons are stuck together.

Can somebody suggest how I can correct this so that there is always a consistent space between these buttons?

Comment: Consistent and IE in the same sentence...interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried putting `&nbsp;` in between them?

IE does not render "padding" to W3C standards.  (See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) for explanation.)  That's almost assuredly where this problem is coming from, so you'll need to insert something in between them to make it work properly.

Comment: this is far from ideal, considering now my HTML is littered with `&nbsp;`. It works though. Thanks.

Comment: Another alternative would be to adjust the box model method ( http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ ), but then you'll probably start having browser compatibility issues.  Unfortunately, I doubt there is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `margin-left` property to move the button some pixels right such as `margin-left:3px`, but first you have to remove the whitespace between the `input` and `button`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2HP43/18/

Answer (score 2):

This solves my problem:

```
*padding: 2px; /* "*" is for lte IE 7 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="Submit1" value="Remove" name="btnRemoveFunds">&nbsp;<button class="button" id="Button1">Add More Funds</button>
```

`&nbsp;` ensures you have a space in there

Answer (score 0):

this might help you to solve the problem

```
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have 3 solutions to this problem:

1. The easiest is to use `&nbsp;` but of course this can't be used professionally.
2. Use `padding` property
3. Use the `margin-left` property.